# Proof that if E2 ⊂ E1 then Pr(E2 | H) <= Pr(E1 | H)

Tags: probability

As stated in the title I am trying to prove that if 'E2 ⊂ E1' then 'Pr(E2 | H) <= Pr(E1 | H)'

The key idea here is that if E2 is a subset of E1 then it cannot be that the probability of E2 conditional on H is greater than that of E1 conditional on H.

I understand this geometrically (see the picture I drew) but am not sure how to prove it formally.

[Geometric Proof that if E2 ⊂ E1 then Pr(E2 | H) <= Pr(E1 | H)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwmoi.png)

[image]

Comment: Hint:  $E_1$ is the disjoint union of $E_2$ and $E_1\,/\ E_2$.

Comment: Thanks @lulu Im looking up 'disjoint union' but I'm not a mathematician so that terminology is even less familiar territory for me with talk of "onto" mappings etc in Wikipedia! I'll keep trying though.

Comment: Disjoint union: cut your space into a bunch of non-overlapping pieces so that you can still glue them together to form the original space.

Comment: What do you know about Pr? For example, do you know that Pr(A or B) ≥ Pr(A)?

Comment: A set $A$ is the disjoint union of sets $B$ and $C$ if $B\cap C=\emptyset$ and $A=B\cup C$.

Comment: And $E_1\,\ / \,E_2$ means "the set consisting of those elements of $E_1$ which are not in $E_2$."

Comment: So the way I understand this geometrically is that the maximal region that E2 could take up in the H region is the conjunction of E1&H. As the Pr(E2 | H) = Pr(E2&H)/Pr(H). It cannot be the case that Pr(E2|H)>Pr(E1|H). I just don't know how to formally prove it now!

Comment: It's not a geometric issue.  Disjoint events add in probability.  That is, if $A,B$ are disjoint events then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$.  Apply that here.

Comment: @lulu I honestly don't understand what/how Im supposed to apply that, Im trying. So Pr(E1|H)=Pr(E1&H)/Pr(H), Pr(H or E1)=Pr(H)+Pr(E1)... idk

Comment: So, take $A=E_2$ and $B=E_1\, /E_2$.  Then you can see that $E_1=A\cup B$ and  $A\cap B=\emptyset$, right?  So then $P(E_1)=P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)=P(E_2)+P(E_1\,/\, E_2)$

Comment: Should say:  We are, of course, assuming that all these sets actually have probabilities attached to them.  That's an (important) technical assumption which you didn't mention but which I imagine you intended.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Assuming non-zero credences towards each proposition and assuming a Bayesian interpretation. Im talking about epistemic possibility and trying to show that it cannot both be the case that the probability of any life conditional on Theism is low (i.e. that God would want to create a world containing just worms) but this is inconsistent with believing that the probability of embodied moral agents conditional on Theism (which many Theists claim is intuitively high).

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the help but Im still struggling to see the formal proof here. This might just be because I don't have formal training in Mathematics but should I be thinking direct proof, or proof by contradiction or something else in order to prove the statement in the title as a theorem?

Comment: I have written a formal proof.  All that remains is to remark that $P(S)≥0$ for any event $S$ (that has a probability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of probability, if $A\subset B$, then $B = (B\setminus A) \cup A \implies P(B) \geq P(A)$.

Conditioning on another event $E$ doesn't change the fact that $A\implies B$ therefore,

$$P(B|E) = \frac{P(B\cap E)}{P(E)} = \frac{P(((B\setminus A) \cup A)\cap E)}{P(E)}=\frac{P(((B\setminus A) \cap E) \cup (A\cap E))}{P(E)}= \frac{P((B\setminus A) \cap E) + P(A\cap E))}{P(E)} = \frac{P((B\setminus A) \cap E) + P(A\cap E))}{P(E)}$$
$$= P(B\setminus A|E) + P(A|E) \geq P(A|E)\;\;\;\square$$

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use the definition of conditional probability which is:

$P(E|H)=\dfrac{P(E\bigcap H)}{P(H)}$. Then, since $E_{1}\subseteq\,E_{2}$ we get $E_{1}\bigcap\,H\,\subseteq\,E_{2}\bigcap\,H$ and hence

$P(E_{1}\bigcap\,H)\,\leq\,P(E_{2}\bigcap\,H)$ from which the result follows.

Comment: Thanks -- I did it as: 

If 'E2  E1’ then  'Pr(E2|H)Pr(E1|H)' 

Suppose that Pr(E1)0, Pr(E2)0, and Pr(H)0. Also that E2E1, and Pr(E2|H)0. 
Since E2E1, it follows that (E2  H) (E1  H); Hence, Pr(E2  H) Pr(E1  H)
The definition of conditional probability gives us the formula for the probability of
E2 conditional on H as:  Pr(E2 | H) =Pr(E2  H)Pr(H) , and
E1 conditional on H as:  Pr(E1 | H) =Pr(E1  H)Pr(H) 
Since Pr(H) is the same in both cases, and Pr(E2  H) Pr(E1  H), it follows that  
Pr(E2 | H)  Pr(E1 | H)